# TISE for Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator

This question involves a wavefunction with only specific solutions for $n$ where it is an eigenfunction of $\hat{H}\psi$. With $\hat{H}$ defined in the 1-D problem as

$$\hat{H} = -\dfrac{\hbar}{2m} \dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}+\dfrac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2$$

and the wavefunction defined as

$$\psi_n(x)=A_nx^ne^{-x^2/(2a^2)}$$

where $A_n$ is a normalization coefficient, the question asks to first evaluate the SE $\hat{H}\psi_n(x)=E_n\psi_n(x)$, then determine what values of $n$ and $a$ satisfy the SE by making $E_n$ independent of $x$.

I tried working through the derivative, but get a long answer (basically [the one that Wolfram Alpha gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx%28d%2Fdx%28x%5En%20e%5E%28-x%5E2%20%2F%20%282a%5E2%29%29%29)) and cannot figure out what values would satisfy the equation. I'm also not seeing any substitutions that can make this easier, although I'm guessing there is one.

Comment: The resulting equation has the simple form $(Bx^{n+2}+Cx^n+Dx^{n-2})e^{-x^2/2a^2}=0$. To be true for all $x$, the three coefficients $B$, $C$, and $D$ must all be zero.

Comment: Sometimes computer algebra results look more complicated than they actually are. (You should just do this differentiation by hand.) But if you look at the algebraic structure, the thing multiplying the exponential is just a polynomial with three powers of $x$.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm not sure that all of it can be set to 0, since it must equal $E_n$, so it should be some constant not dependent on $x$. I get $E_n = (\dfrac{-\hbar^2}{2m}B +\dfrac{1}{2}m\omega^2)x^{n+1} + \dfrac{-\hbar^2}{2m}(Cx^{n-1} + Dx^{x-3})$. The question hints that there are two values for $n$, and one for $a$, and $a$ is in terms of $\hbar$ and $\omega$. So I tried setting the term before $x^{n+1}$ to 0, and set $n=1$ and $n=3$ to make the other terms constant. This gives me $\hbar^2n - \dfrac{\hbar^2}{a^2}=m^2\omega^2a^2$, which gives a large and crazy result for $a$...

Comment: I moved the $E\psi_n$ to the left side so that it is then more obvious that all three coefficients must vanish.

Comment: You seem to have lost the $x^n$ multiplying $E$.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying. I'm getting $B=\dfrac{-n}{a^2}-\dfrac{1}{a^4}$, $C=\dfrac{-n-1}{a^2}$, and $D=n(n-1)$. I see one solution n=1 from D.

Comment: I mean, I see where I lost the $x^n$. I'm still not sure why all the coefficients must vanish. I get $\hat{H}\psi_n(x) = A_n[-\frac{\hbar}{2m}(Bx^{n+2}+Cx^n+Dx^{n-2}) + \dfrac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^{n+2}]e^{-x^2/(2a^2)}$, factoring out the $x^n$ gives me $E_n=\dfrac{-\hbar^2}{2m}(Bx^2+C+Dx^{-2})+\dfrac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2$. Since $E_n != 0$, it needs to just be a constant, so $B$ can be $0$ or $Fx^{-2}$, $D$ can be $0$ or $Gx^2$, and $C$ needn't vanish.

Comment: *Two* solutions from $D$.

Comment: You don’t seem to understand what I meant by $B$, $C$, and $D$. But I’m getting a message to avoid extended discussions in chat, so I’m done.

Comment: Oh, I thought n=0 would give zero energy, but you're right, it seems to work out. I think I can give the rest of this problem a go, will post a full answer next week once it's graded. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The textbook derivation is done in a somewhat different way. One considers a solution in thew form
$$
\Psi_n=A_ne^{-\frac{m\omega x^2}{\hbar}}H_n\left(\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{\hbar}x}\right)
$$
and then, this is substituted into the equation
$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi_n}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2\psi_n=E_n\psi_n.
$$
You will get an equation for $H_n$ that can be solved through polynomials (Hermite polynomials) provided the condition
$$
E_n=(2n+1)\frac{\hbar\omega}{2}
$$
is met otherwise you have no solution at all. A good starting point for this kind of approach is [Landau-Lifshitz book on non-relativistic quantum mechanics](https://books.google.it/books?id=SvdoN3k8EysC&printsec=frontcover&hl=it&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false).